# Spring Data elasticsearch UpdateQuery withRefreshPolicy not working

Tags: java, kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use `ElasticsearchOperations` to implement update operations.

```kotlin
esOperations.update(
    UpdateQuery.builder(old.id.toString())
        .withDocument(Document.from(mapOf("browsed" to item.browsed)))
        .withRefreshPolicy(
            RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE
        )
        .build(),
    IndexCoordinates.of("t_telegram_message")
)
```

But it's not working properly, the post request is

```
POST /t_telegram_message/_update/6150?refresh=false
```

What I expect is that the request parameter is `refresh=true`.

what should I do?

Dependencies:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>5.0.3</version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in Spring Data Elasticsearch, thanks for reporting; I just fixed it in *main* and backported it to the 5.1 and 5.0 branches.

Comment: I used version 5.1.3, but this error still exists. Is it because the fixed version has not been released to the maven repository?

Comment: Yes, when issues are fixed and backported, they will only be available with the next release. But you're lucky, 5.2.0-M3, 5.1.4 and 5.0.10 have just been released, so the y should be available in maven central soon.